# mysql tables mysteriously emptied

Tags: mysql, recovery

I noticed that a couple of my mysql tables today were emptied.  I can't think of any reason why this would occur.  I store the DB in an AWS volume and we are well under the amount of space allocated to us. I was wondering if anyone had this issue before? Any suggestions of things that I can test?  Sorry if I haven't provided enough information; its because I can't think of anything that would have caused this.  Feel free to ask away.

Answer (score 0):

How about a delete statement? Bad code, bad security permissions, SQL injection etc

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  It could be poor code but there is nothing that I've written that could possibly delete a table. I can't imagine how someone would get access to our server. I've set the password and username and haven't told anyone.  Finally, I don't think its SQL injection because we are using a PHP framework.  I never insert things directly into the database but use Propel.  I'm not sure if this is true, but Propel *should* prevent SQL injections

Comment: ok this it totally harebrained, but is there any chance that it had ot do with daylight savings time?  I'm sure it doesn't but the issue occurred between 1 and 2:30 AM today.